# $matches is returning same value in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I have array of links, i am trying to match using `preg_match_all,regex` but it is giving me the same result each and every time

```php
foreach ($result[0] as $temp) {
    preg_match_all($regex1, $temp["content"], $matches);
    $storeUrl[]= $matches;
}
foreach ($storeUrl as $tem) {
    preg_match_all($regex2, $tem[],$matches);
    $storeUrllist [$count1++]= $matches;
}
```

`$matches` is working fine for first foreach and second foreach it is always returning same output only even it is not matching

Comment: need to see `$storeUrl` and `$regex2`

Comment: @tim thanks for reply, $regex2=/^\b\w{5}+[:\/\/]+\w+\.+\w+.(org|org2|com)\b/ and $storeurl is an array which contains huge links, let us take one link https://www.stackoverflow.org/exercise/avg-gfdg-of-gdh-gdg-gfdg

Comment: It is working fine when i test in https://regex101.com/ but in code $matches returns same data only

Comment: `$tem[]` should just be `$tem`

Comment: I tried that option also @Tim

Comment: But it is returning same results, even though it is not matching

Comment: ive tested it, works as expected, so it relates to your actual input. http://ideone.com/W1VzNr

Comment: Thanks @Tim, for me "https://www.stackoverflow.org/exercise/avg-gfdg-of-gdh-gdg-gfdg" i am trying to match with this url now it is returning storeurl[0][0]="https://www.stackoverflow.org" and storeurl[0][1]="org" which is not required, how can i remove org??

Comment: feels like this is a new question, as should be asked as one

Comment: Any how thank you so much @Tim.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that you might want to design an expression that'd be similar to:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?\w+\.(?:org|org2|com)\b
```

or:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?\w+\.(?:org|org2|com)\b
```

or:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)\w+\.(?:org|org2|com)\b
```

not sure though.

#### Test

```
$re = '/\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?\w+\.(?:org|org2|com)\b/m';
$str = 'some content http://alice.com or https://bob.org or https://www.foo.com or or baz.org2 ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "http://alice.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "https://bob.org"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "https://www.foo.com"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "baz.org2"
  }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dZDkPc/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/dZDkPc/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  above three regexp will returning domain also, could you please help to form a regex which it will check  whether sub domain is there are not if it contains then only it needs to give the results

Comment: example: https://www.stackoverflow.org/exercise/clusters--gaps--peaks--and-outliers  it contains sub  domain so the expected result is  https://www.stackoverflow.org , lets take a other scenario https://stackoverflow.org/exercise/fskf--gaps--peaks--and-outliers in this case no need to return any thing